# How can I access profile Admin Colour Scheme

Tags: admin, wp-admin, profiles

In WordPress, the user is able to set the default `Admin Colour Scheme` by going to their profile and selecting a color scheme, how can I access those color schemes?

For example, when `Midnight` is selected, the sidebar color changes, and etc. I want to access those colors. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

The current active/selected admin color scheme is a user setting, you can get its value with `get_user_option( 'admin_color' )`.

```
$admin_color = get_user_option( 'admin_color' );
```

if you want to access the color scheme for the specific user then pass the user id as second parameter in the `get_user_option()` function

```
$user1_id = 2;
$user1_color = get_user_option( 'admin_color', $user1_id );
```

the above both examples will return the name of the active color scheme e.g; blue, fresh, Midnight etc..

if you want to access the whole list of colors used in the admin section then use the following..

```
global $_wp_admin_css_colors; 
$admin_colors = $_wp_admin_css_colors;
print_r($admin_colors);
```